# c++ "Class X is not a template type"

Tags: c++

i have been working with this, and now that it almost ready a get this error from the compiler: "Class Servant is not a template Type"
i have been reading other forums post about this issue, but i not see any problem ( my self but  the compiler yes!), can get any help?
thx in advance, here is the code

```
static int aDefaultValue=0;
//class T;
template <typename T>
class Servant
{
public:
    typedef typename T & ReferenceType;
    typedef const typename T * ConstPtrType;
    typedef typename T * ptrType;
    Servant(){}

    ptrType analizarQos(ptrType aMetodo= 0,int & aResult = aDefaultValue)
    {
        if (!aMetodo)
        {
            aResult=-1;
            return aMetodo;
        }
        //check for timeout del metodo
        //lleno el mensaje con la info

    }

private:
    ~Servant(){}
    //avoid copias
    Servant(const Servant &);
    const Servant & operator=(const Servant &);
};
```

Comment: Can you please point out *where* you get that error?

Comment: You don't need to use the keyword `typename` in your typedefs.

Comment: After you fixed those `typename` issues, [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) please.

Comment: i have fix up those typename, but the error continues....

Comment: This compiled with g++-4.6.2 after removing the erroneous `typename`s in the `typedef`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clang prints out

```
/private/tmp/my.cpp:7:22: error: expected a qualified name after 'typename'
typedef typename T & ReferenceType;
                 ^
/private/tmp/my.cpp:8:28: error: expected a qualified name after 'typename'
typedef const typename T * ConstPtrType;
                       ^
/private/tmp/my.cpp:9:22: error: expected a qualified name after 'typename'
typedef typename T * ptrType;
                 ^
3 errors generated.
```

Code compiled after I changed to:

```
typedef T & ReferenceType;
typedef const T * ConstPtrType;
typedef T * ptrType;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need

```
Servant(const Servant<T> &);
const Servant & operator=(const Servant<T> &);
```

for the forbidden operations (at least for compilers not supporting 'injected-class-name').

May be you have a forward declaration of class `Servant`, without specifying any template parameters, or the wrong number of template parameters there.

Comment: No, look up injected-class-name.

Comment: sorry, was an error in redefinition of the class, beside i have fixed with those line and works fine! thx!

Comment: @Ricardo_arg what compiler are you using? Because this answer is incorrect for standard C++.

Comment: you r ritgh, but it is accepted by the compiler. i have undone those lines.

Comment: @juanchopanza From which standard on? I remember I had to to have copy constructors and any other methods accepting a reference or pointer to the actual template class this way, otherwise getting compile errors (at least with GCC 4.6x).

Comment: @Ricardo_arg _'sorry, was an error in redefinition of the class'_ Could you edit(update) your question accordingly, or answer yourself? Otherwise I'd guess Dieter_Lücking's answer might be probably right.

Comment: For as long as I can remember. I guess it as there in C++98.